# If $\{v, w\}$ is a basis for $V$, is it necessarily true that $\{v+w, v-w\}$ is a basis for $V$? Hint: No

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm really stuck: I tried to do a proof by contradiction to prove the claim false but I couldn't get a contradiction. So I suppose I need to come up with a counter example. In terms of general problem-solving heuristics, how does one conceive of a counter example?

Comment: What field did you have in mind?  If the characteristic is $2$ then...

Comment: @lulu Yeah, I'm confused by that too. The problem didn't specify a field. Is the point of the problem to think of a field to prove this claim false?

Comment: The whole point is that $$ \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = -2.$$ Thus $\{ v+w, v-w\}$ is a basis iff $-2$ is different from zero in your base field.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm using Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right and it doesn't look at determinants for most of the book, and so I don't toally follow. But I notice that it seems if the field is mod2, then v-w = v+w, and so {v+w,v+w} is not a basis for {v,w}

Comment: Oh ok :) still it is nice to know that for all other characteristics you will still get a basis.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for your help - this is my first proof-based math class, and so I'm a bit shaky on the concept of a field/proofs in general

Comment: The problem likely expects you to observe that if $char(F)\neq 2$ then this is a basis, while when $char(F)=2$ you have $v+w=v-w$ so the two vectors are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a formal proof, it's best to immediately write assumptions and what you want to prove formally. In your case the assumptions are:

1. $(\forall \alpha,\beta\in F)\quad\alpha v + \beta w = 0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0,$
2. $V = \operatorname{span}_F \{v,w\}$.

What you would like to prove or disprove is:

3. $(\forall \alpha,\beta\in F) \quad \alpha(v+w) + \beta(v-w) = 0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0,$
4. $V = \operatorname{span}_F \{v+w,v-w\}$.

First of all, since we know that $\{v,w\}$ is a basis, we know that $\dim V = 2$, and having that in mind, 3. and 4. are equivalent. Thus, it is enough to prove or disprove one of them.

I will concentrate on 3., so take $\alpha,\beta\in F$ such that $\alpha(v+w) + \beta(v-w) = 0$. We want to manipulate this expression:

\begin{align}
\alpha(v+w) + \beta(v-w) = 0 &\implies (\alpha + \beta)v+(\alpha - \beta)w = 0\\
&\stackrel{1.}{\implies} \alpha + \beta = 0\ \wedge\ \alpha -\beta = 0\\
&\implies \alpha = \beta\ \wedge \ 2\alpha = 0.
\end{align}

At this point, the field $F$ becomes relevant. If $\operatorname{char} F \neq 2$, then $2\in F$ is invertible, and $2\alpha = 0\implies \alpha = 0$, and therefore $\beta = \alpha = 0$. So, in this case, we started from $\alpha(v+w) + \beta(v-w) = 0$ and concluded $\alpha = \beta = 0$ and thus proved that 3. is true, i.e. $\{v+w,v-w\}$ is indeed a basis for $V$.

However, if $\operatorname{char} F = 2$, then $2\alpha = 0$ is true for all $\alpha\in F$, and we can't conclude that $\alpha = 0$. But that doesn't disprove 3. yet. For that, we need a counterexample. Choose $\alpha = \beta = 1 \in F$. Then $$\alpha(v+w) + \beta(v-w) = (v+w)+(v-w) = 2v = 0,$$ but $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\beta \neq 0$. Therefore, we provided a counterexample to 3., so $\{v+w,v-w\}$ is not a basis for $V$.

Comment: Wow!!! That was amazing. Thank you so very much. 10/10!!

Answer (score 0):

A basis for an n dimensional vector space has three properties

1. It spans the space.
2. The vectors are independent.
3. There are n vectors.

And any two of those is enough to prove the third.   Since v and w form a basis for V, V has dimension 2. v+w and v-w are are 2 vectors so it is only necessary to show **either** that v+ w  and v- w span the space **or** that they are independent.

To show that they are independent look at a(v+ w)+ b(v-w)= 0 for some a and b.  a(v+ w)+ b(v- w)= av+ aw+ bv- bw= (a+ b)v+ (a- b)w= 0.  Since v and w are independent we must have a+ b= 0 and a- b= 0.  Adding those, 2a= 0 so a= 0 and then b= 0, proving that v+ w and v- w are independent and so a basis for V.

Comment: "$2a=0$ so $a=0$" is not true in all fields.